# would this code delete the last node in linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

Its just a code snippet, but considering everything else has been coded right, would this logically delete the last node? Or is my logic faulty?

Question answered.

Comment: It would throw an exception because current would be null.

Comment: Perhaps you want `while(current.next != null) { ... }` and `previous.next = null;`

Comment: Yeah I just the mistake, previous.next = null; would delete the last node indeed. The other codes was a nonsensical at the end.

Comment: Wait would it not be more correct to say previous = null; since previus is pointing to the last node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the code would throw an exception as `current` would be `null` after exiting the `while` loop. The correct version of the method (with deletion from a specific position) might look something like the following:

```
public static Node delete(Node head, int position)
{
    Node traverse = head;
    if(position == 0) { 
        //remember this case
        head = head.next;
        return head;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < position; i++)
        traverse = traverse.next;

    Node deleteit = traverse.next; //want to skip over this node
    traverse.next = deleteit.next; 

    return head;
}
```

Comment: My final revision does this:   void delete()

{

//both initialized at the start.

LinkedNode current = list;

LinkedNode previous = list;



while(current != null)
{
previous = current;
current = current.next;
}



//delete the last node
previous = null;



}

Comment: Umm...the question is tagged as "java" - I bet an answer in Java would be more useful and appropriate.

Comment: Oh, right. Give me a minute and I'll add a java implementation.